# A container with three divs and a display of grid; but the third div gets pushed down although it has space above it

Tags: html, css, grid

As you can see the red rectangle (drew it myself; it isn't located in the codes) is the free space below my main-left-section and the right section is the div that causing this issue, and i couldn't find the fix for it.

also i tried seting a 100vh height for my right section and temporarily fixes the issue; but when i try to make my page responsive, the comment section gets placed on top of my right section.

[have not set a height for right-section, so it pushes the comment section down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSVHh.jpg)

[set some random heights for right-section and it temporarily fixes the issue, but causes this issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWDId.jpg)

overview of the HTML and CSS:

```css
.main-container {
  padding-top: var(--main-margin-top);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--video-width) var(--main-right-section-width);
  gap: var(--default-gap);
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
  .main-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container"> 
  <div class="main-left-section"></div>
  <div class="main-right-section"></div>
  <div class="main-comment-section"></div>
</div>`
```

Tried setting different heights, grid values and etc.. but didn't achieve the desired results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for using grid here? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can help.

Comment: either replace your css variables with value or also add the values of variables in code. Also try to create minimal producible example.